# Cambiar el color de una caja en estado hover de un snip1281 CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una maqueta y estoy utilizando unos snip1281 que tienen efecto en los hover, cada imagen o carrera tiene un efecto hover de una linea top con color y una caja con el mismo color sobre un texto blanco, pero todas las carreras tienen un color distinto osea que cada caja en su estado hover tendrá su color representativo.

> ¿COMO PUEDO APLICAR LOS DISTINTOS COLORES A LOS ESTADOS HOVER Y
>   DIFERENCIAR A PARTIR DEL CSS SIN HACER REPETICIÓN DE CÓDIGO?.

Es decir no tener que a cada imagen ponerle snip1281 snip1282 etc etc. [image: IMAGEN]

```js
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

```css
figure.snip1281 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 315px;
  max-height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

figure.snip1281 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1281 img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

figure.snip1281:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1281.hover figcaption {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

figure.snip1281:hover h3,
figure.snip1281.hover h3 {
  color: #333;
}

figure.snip1281 h2,
figure.snip1281 span {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281 h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  width: 233px;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue57CondensedOblique';
  left: 12px;
}

figure.snip1281 a {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1281:after {
  background: #000000;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281.blue:after {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

figure.snip1281.red:after {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

figure.snip1281.yellow:after {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

figure.snip1281.green:after {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

figure.snip1281:hover img,
figure.snip1281.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="carreras">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
        <figure class="snip1281 yellow">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample22.jpg" alt="sample22" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Gordon Norman</h2>

          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
        <figure class="snip1281 blue">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
        <figure class="snip1281 red">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
        <figure class="snip1281 celeste">
          <img src="images/educacion.jpg" alt="educacion" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Educación</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
        <figure class="snip1281 yellow">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample22.jpg" alt="sample22" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Gordon Norman</h2>

          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
        <figure class="snip1281 blue">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
        <figure class="snip1281 red">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
        <figure class="snip1281 celeste">
          <img src="images/educacion.jpg" alt="educacion" />
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Educación</h2>
          </figcaption>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quita el background-color: #f39c12; de la clase y utiliza el pseudo elemento nth-child() para personalizar cada uno sin necesidad de escribir todo el codigo de nuevo.

```js
  $(".hover").mouseleave(
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
  );
```

```css
figure.snip1281 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 1%;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 315px;
    max-height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

figure.snip1281 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1281 img {
    opacity: 0.7;
    max-width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281 figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

figure.snip1281:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1281.hover figcaption {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
}

figure.snip1281:hover h3,
figure.snip1281.hover h3 {
    color: #333;
}

figure.snip1281 h2,
figure.snip1281 span {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281 h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    width: 233px;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue57CondensedOblique';
    left: 12px;
}

figure.snip1281 a {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

figure.snip1281:after {
    background: #000000;
    width: 0;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

figure.snip1281:hover .blue {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}

figure.snip1281:hover .red {
    background-color: #c0392b;
}

figure.snip1281:hover .yellow {
    background-color: #f39c12;
}

figure.snip1281:hover .green {
    background-color: #27ae60;
}

figure.snip1281:hover img,
figure.snip1281.hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

figure.snip1281:hover:after,
figure.snip1281.hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="carreras">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample22.jpg" alt="sample22" />
                <figcaption class="yellow">
                    <h2>Gordon Norman</h2>

                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
                <figcaption class="blue">
                    <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
                <figcaption class="green">
                    <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-2">
            <figure class="snip1281 azul">
                <img src="images/educacion.jpg" alt="educacion" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Educación</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample22.jpg" alt="sample22" />
                <figcaption class="green">
                    <h2>Gordon Norman</h2>

                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
                <figcaption class="blue">
                    <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample20.jpg" alt="sample20" />
                <figcaption class="green">
                    <h2>Bailey Wonger</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
            <figure class="snip1281">
                <img src="images/educacion.jpg" alt="educacion" />
                <figcaption class="red">
                    <h2>Educación</h2>
                </figcaption>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: ahhh excelente!!! no lo tuve en cuenta a eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te puedo hacer una consulta @qqwweerrtty, resulta que lo que me pasaste me funciona pero cuando lo quiero poner dentro de cuatros columnas de bootstrap 4 no me aplica los estilos del hover. sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Necesito que me muestres el código fuente y junto con eso puedo resolver tu problema.

Comment: dale ahi lo edito

Comment: ahi lo edite arriba, el problema es que no me reconoce los colores de los child

Comment: He editado el código fuente, estaba bien lo que tratabas de hacer en colocar una clase independiente pero estaba mal colocada, la estabas colocando en <figure class="snip1281 red"> cuando iba en el  <figcaption class="green">

Comment: ahh okey! si me parecía raro, porque independientemente sin los col andaban todo bien, yo pensé que había algo de boostrap algún css  que traban el funcionamiento. muchas gracias